# MyIntervals API multiple persons contact information in one request

Tags: php, api

I'm trying to make app that use [myintervals API](http://www.myintervals.com/api/).

And I need to check for project members contact information.

In order to make API call for each person for it contacts, I'd like to dump contacts for all persons in project(or company), so I could make 1 API request, not a 100.

Unfortunately I didn't found how to perform such request.
May I have some help about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the API definition the person resource expects an integer so there isn't a way to exclude it or add more than one id via a comma-delimited list of people ids.

http://www.myintervals.com/api/resource.php?r=personcontact

The only way to get at them will be one per request. Try sending an email to support to see if the requirement can be lifted or modified to allow multiple ids to be sent.

Comment: I sent email to support, and they told me that there are not possibility to get several person-contacts at once.